# Bright patterns in the Dry Andes

Tags: geomorphology, satellite-oddities

I am doing some preliminary research on aeolian/nival landforms in Andes and I came across this:

[image: bright polygonish nets]

located at [-24.950948, -68.268528](https://www.google.com/maps/place/24%C2%B057%2703.4%22S+68%C2%B016%2706.7%22W/@-24.950958,-68.2688391,1090m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x6698177a50c86e8!8m2!3d-24.9509483!4d-68.268528) and other locations throughout the Argentinian Dry Andes. Any idea what could these landforms be?

Thanks!
V.

Comment: Just a wild guess: the area is surrounded by salt flats, so it could have something to do with this (like remnants of an old salt lake maybe).

Answer (score 1):

It could be some kind of shallow-rooted grasses. A little to the south those features appear to separate into different colors. Though I think this unlikely because your location is in a concave part of the landscape...so unstable for vegetation.
[image: change in color further south]